Locating cause of soft lockups on Ubuntu on Azure
Kernel version: 6.5.0-1022-azure
For a couple of months I've been experiencing occasional issues with Ubuntu instances going into soft lockup, and I'm looking to find the cause.
I have 8 Virtual Machines running from an identical image (using an Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set), and it is machines in one particular Azure zone that are experiencing the issue.
Extract from the syslog is provided below. How can I determine what the underlying cause of the soft lockups is? The times it occurs doesn't seem to relate to busy times for the VM, or anything else I can see.
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y process-agent[4716]: 2024-06-21 23:43:03 BST | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:191 in process) | Error while processing transaction: error while sending transaction, rescheduling it: Post "https://process.datadoghq.eu/api/v1/collector": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y agent[4707]: 2024-06-21 23:42:56 BST | CORE | WARN | (pkg/collector/python/datadog_agent.go:131 in LogMessage) | disk:67cc0574430a16ba | (disk.py:128) | Timeout after 5 seconds while retrieving the disk usage of `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` mountpoint. You might want to change the timeout length in the settings.
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y python3[10161]: 2024-06-21T22:43:06.080818Z WARNING MonitorHandler ExtHandler Error in SendHostPluginHeartbeat: [HttpError] [HTTP Failed] GET http://168.63.129.16:32526/health -- IOError timed out -- 1 attempts made --- [NOTE: Will not log the same error for the next hour]
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y trace-agent[4730]: 2024-06-21 23:43:05 BST | TRACE | INFO | (pkg/trace/info/stats.go:98 in LogAndResetStats) | [lang:ruby lang_version:3.2.2 interpreter:ruby-x86_64-linux tracer_version:1.20.0 endpoint_version:v0.4] -> traces received: 26, traces filtered: 19, traces amount: 643398 bytes, events extracted: 0, events sampled: 0
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y chronyd[5200]: Can't synchronise: no selectable sources
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.744639] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 30s! [kworker/u8:6:3082536]
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751605] Modules linked in: nvme_fabrics udf crc_itu_t xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_owner xt_tcpudp nft_compat nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 mlx5_ib ib_uverbs ib_core mlx5_core tls crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul mlxfw polyval_clmulni joydev polyval_generic psample hid_generic serio_raw ghash_clmulni_intel hyperv_drm sha256_ssse3 sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel drm_kms_helper hid_hyperv hid hv_netvsc crypto_simd drm_shmem_helper cryptd hyperv_keyboard dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua drm sch_fq_codel i2c_core efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751692] CPU: 0 PID: 3082536 Comm: kworker/u8:6 Tainted: G             L     6.5.0-1022-azure #23~22.04.1-Ubuntu
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751697] Hardware name: Microsoft Corporation Virtual Machine/Virtual Machine, BIOS Hyper-V UEFI Release v4.1 03/08/2024
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751700] Workqueue: efi_rts_wq efi_call_rts
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751708] RIP: 0010:__do_softirq+0x6f/0x2de
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751716] Code: ff f7 ff ff 89 75 bc 65 81 05 11 4d 44 55 00 01 00 00 c7 45 d0 0a 00 00 00 65 66 c7 05 20 4d 44 55 00 00 fb 41 ba ff ff ff ff <49> c7 c3 c0 60 c0 ab 45 0f bc d4 41 83 c2 01 4c 89 db 45 89 d6 0f
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751719] RSP: 0018:ffffa33080003f68 EFLAGS: 00000206
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751723] RAX: ffff8d64170fe600 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000034000000
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751726] RDX: 0000000104981ea3 RSI: 0000000004208060 RDI: ffff8d66afc20040
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751729] RBP: ffffa33080003fb8 R08: 0002925f5102a7c8 R09: 29ac788fc357422b
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751732] R10: 00000000ffffffff R11: ffffa33080003ff8 R12: 0000000000000048
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751735] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751742] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8d66afc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751746] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751749] CR2: 000060bd9addcae0 CR3: 000000010020c000 CR4: 0000000000350ef0
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751752] Call Trace:
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751755]  <IRQ>
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751760]  ? show_regs+0x6a/0x80
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751767]  ? watchdog_timer_fn+0x1ce/0x230
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751773]  ? __pfx_watchdog_timer_fn+0x10/0x10
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751777]  ? __hrtimer_run_queues+0x111/0x240
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751785]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751791]  ? hrtimer_interrupt+0x101/0x240
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751795]  ? enqueue_entity+0x1ce/0x550
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751801]  ? hv_stimer0_isr+0x20/0x30
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751805]  ? __sysvec_hyperv_stimer0+0x32/0x70
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751809]  ? sysvec_hyperv_stimer0+0x3e/0x90
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751815]  ? asm_sysvec_hyperv_stimer0+0x1b/0x20
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751823]  ? __do_softirq+0x6f/0x2de
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751829]  __irq_exit_rcu+0xb0/0xd0
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751835]  irq_exit_rcu+0xe/0x20
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751839]  sysvec_hyperv_callback+0x80/0x90
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751844]  </IRQ>
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751846]  <TASK>
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751848]  asm_sysvec_hyperv_callback+0x1b/0x20
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751852] RIP: 0010:0xfffffffefff59183
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751870] Code: 48 8b 5c 24 40 48 8b 7c 24 50 48 83 c4 30 41 5f c3 cc cc 66 90 44 8b 05 b3 25 00 00 b8 24 00 00 00 48 8b 15 e7 25 00 00 90 ef <90> 41 8b c0 48 8b 15 da 25 00 00 90 48 83 c2 04 ef 90 48 8b 05 9c
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751873] RSP: 0018:ffffa33089b83c48 EFLAGS: 00000246
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751876] RAX: 0000000000000024 RBX: 0000000000000036 RCX: fffffffefffc3000
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751879] RDX: 0000000000000028 RSI: ffffa3308657fd70 RDI: 0000000000000000
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751882] RBP: ffffa33089b83e08 R08: 000000003ffc3000 R09: ffffa33089b83cb5
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751884] R10: 0000000000000034 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffa3308657fd1c
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751886] R13: ffffa3308657fd60 R14: ffffa3308657fd60 R15: ffffa3308657fd70
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751895]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751899]  ? newidle_balance+0x363/0x440
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751904]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751908]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x10
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751912]  ? psi_group_change+0x237/0x4d0
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751916]  ? pick_next_task_fair+0x49/0x5b0
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751922]  ? __efi_call+0x28/0x30
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751927]  ? switch_mm+0x12/0x30
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751932]  ? efi_enter_mm+0x39/0x40
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751936]  ? efi_call_rts+0x216/0x660
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751940]  ? process_one_work+0x22e/0x420
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751945]  ? worker_thread+0x50/0x3f0
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751949]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751953]  ? kthread+0xd6/0x100
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751957]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751962]  ? ret_from_fork+0x3c/0x60
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751967]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751971]  ? ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
23:43:06 scaleset-00000Y kernel: [308602.751978]  </TASK>
23:43:27 scaleset-00000Y process-agent[4716]: 2024-06-21 23:43:13 BST | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/default_forwarder.go:697 in func3) | timed out waiting for responses, received 0/1
23:43:27 scaleset-00000Y process-agent[4716]: 2024-06-21 23:43:27 BST | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:191 in process) | Error while processing transaction: error while sending transaction, rescheduling it: Post "https://process.datadoghq.eu/api/v1/collector": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
23:43:27 scaleset-00000Y process-agent[4716]: 2024-06-21 23:43:27 BST | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:187 in process) | Too many errors for endpoint 'https://process.datadoghq.eu/api/v1/collector': retrying later
23:43:27 scaleset-00000Y chronyd[5200]: Selected source PHC0 ```



You don't have control over the host unfortunately, which very much limits what you can attempt. Are the affected instances running on the same server? The only possible VM-related issue that I can suggest looking into, judging from the logs, is that something is making calls to an API which is not responding (some "Datadog" service). I doubt it could cause a soft lockup though?

Too many years experience with Azure and EC2 generally point to IO bottlenecks being the cause for soft lockups and poor VM performance. If the instance uses lots of little files or a semi-consistent database, then you may run into this sort of thing more often than you’d like. With Azure, I have found the instances on the west coast of the US to be the most IO constrained. With EC2, it’s us-east-2. Only solution is to get a bigger instance with better IO or move to a different zone
